# Disable write intent bitmap on LVM RAID1

Tags: linux, debian, raid, lvm

I want to use LVM on raw devices to be able to dynamically create RAID0 and RAID1 volumes depending on my current needs. I've recently learned that the write intent bitmap feature of `mdadm` reduces available IOPS a lot. In my case I'm getting only a third of IOPS that I should be getting.

Is it possible to create an LVM RAID1 logical volume without a write intent bitmap? I can deal with drawbacks, as the volumes I plan to create will never be large, hence I do not expect that rebuild time will be too long.

This is Debian Buster.

Answer (score 1):

I observe that setting `--regionsize 64` (or probably some large value depending on the size of the volume so that the intent bitmap fits in a small number of blocks) mitigates the effect to a reasonable degree, so that the write IOPS are at 85% of single-drive IOPS. This is enough for my current purposes, but does not answer the original question, so I won't be accepting this answer.

A reference link: https://listman.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2016-November/023835.html

`lvconvert --regionsize 64m your-volume-group/your-logical-volume` can change this parameter online.